# Hide certain class methods depending on load criteria

Tags: python, function, class, methods

I have a class which I use to handle three types of data structures.
In this class I have many plotting methods, which depends on which type of data is loaded into the class.
Is there a way for me to hide the methods not belonging to the data structure loaded, when looking at the class attributes?

Example:

```
class data_reader():
     def __init__(self):
          self.load_data()
          self.data_type()
          self.common_method_1()
          self.common_method_2()
     
     def load_data(self):
          # Loads the data

     def data_type(self):
          # Figures out which of the three data structures we have

     def common_method_1(self):
          # A method common for all data structures

     def common_method_2(self):
          # Another method common for all data structures

     def plot_data_1(self):
          # Plotting function for data structure 1

     def plot_data_2(self):
          # Plot function for data structure 2

     def plot_data_3(self):
          # Plot function for data structure 3

if __name__ == "__main__":

     a = data_reader()
     a.plot_data_1()
```

When I check the methods of the class I can see all plot functions. If I load data structure 1, can I then hide the other two plotting function?

I tried to do some inner functions, but then it did not become a callable method outside the class.

Thank you for any inputs.

Comment: Rethink your class structure - does it really make sense for them to be the same class? Move common methods to parent class, and make a specific class that inherits from that parent for each data type.

Comment: Based on your comment, I looked up Inner classes or nested classes, and they seem to somewhat do the trick, by adding another attribute layer, so: a.data1.plot() or a.data2.plot(). Thank you for the comment!

Answer (score 2):

My approach to this depend on how "different" your various data structures are:

**V1:**
Not so different, e.g, nested list vs numpy array. In this case I would advise you to write different data load functions, which always convert the data to a common format, e.g.:

```
def load_list_data(self, data):
    # reads a list and converts it to a numpy array

def load_npy_array_data(self, data):
    # reads a numpy array which does not need to be converted

def plot_data(self):
    # plots a numpy array
```

**V2:**
Data differs a lot, e.g., point cloud vs. image. Then use two subclasses and a factory method. Edited version contains a factory method accepting a file path. The path is the opened and the file object passed to the load method:

```
class data_reader():
    def __init__(self, file_object):
        self.load_data(file_object)
        self.data_type()
        self.common_method_1()
        self.common_method_2()

    def load_data(self, file_object):
        # Loads the data
    
    def data_type(self):
        # Figures out which of the three data structures we have

    def common_method_1(self):
        # A method common for all data structures

    def common_method_2(self):
        # Another method common for all data structures

class img_data_read(data_reader):
    def plot_data(self):
        # Plotting function for data structure 1

class pointcloud_data_read(data_reader):
    def plot_data(self):
        # Plotting function for data structure 1

def data_reader_factory(file_path):
    with open(file_path, "r") as f:
        if isinstance(f[FILE_DATA_PATH], IMG_DATA_TYPE):
            return img_data_read(f)
        elif isinstance(f[FILE_DATA_PATH], POINTCLOUD_DATA_TYPE):
            return pointcloud_data_read(f)
```

Then you can do:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":

    a = data_reader_factory()
    a.plot_data()
```

Comment: This here seems to be the one I have gotten closest to working, but one issue I have is that I don't necessarily know the data type before I have loaded the data. Your last function requires that knowledge beforehand. 
The data structures are also completely different and the data object itself is not the only thing I want to transfer into the plot classes. I also want to transfer may other attributes. I tried with a nested class, but there I cannot inherit the attributes to the nested class, resulting in not being able to plot. Do you have any idea how to overcome this, if it makes sense?

Comment: So what is it you have? A file path from which you try loading some data? Once you open that file, will it be clear what kind of data it is? Hard to propose a solution without knowing more specifics.

Comment: Yes, once I open the file, store some attributes specific to that file, I then know what type it is. Essentially I solved the issue by simply running the first part of the "load" class and after knowing the type, I run the whole thing with your proposed method. Probably not the fastest, but it does work quite smoothly.

Comment: I updated my answer a little, how you might go about opening a file only once. The idea is to open the file once in the factory method, then pass the opened object depending on its content to the correct class. But as you wrote, moving the entire loader to the factory would also work.

Answer (score 0):

Methods not relevant to the actual object shouldn't be *hidden*. They should **not be there** in the first place. So instead of making an "universal" object for different data types, extract common logic into the parent class and inherit to specific child classes that define behaviour specific to data types.

Of course, this requires you to know the data type ahead of runtime. If you can only decide that when you actually load the data, I suggest implementing Factory pattern - a separate class that handles the logic of deciding which object to create.

```
class data_reader():
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.common_method_1()
        self.common_method_2()


    def common_method_1(self):
        pass

    def common_method_2(self):
        pass


class data_reader_1(data_reader):
    def plot_data_1(self):
        pass
          # Plotting function for data structure 1
class data_reader_2(data_reader):
    def plot_data_2(self):
        pass
        # Plot function for data structure 2

class data_reader_factory():
    
    def load_data(self):
        self.data = 42
        # Loads the data    

    def data_type(self):
        self.type = "1"
        # Figures out which of the three data structures we have
        

    def create_reader(self):
        if self.type == "1":
            return data_reader_1(self.data)
        elif self.type == "2":
            return data_reader_2(self.data)
        # Creates an object of correct type

if __name__ == "__main__":
    a = data_reader_factory().create_reader()
    a.plot_data_1()
```

Answer (score 0):

Per the comment of `matszwecja`:

Put all common methods in the base class `data_reader` and then create subclasses of this class that override method `plot_data`. The base class no longer needs to know about the various types of plotting. The correct `plot_data` method will be called based on what the actual class is. This is a basic technique in object-oriented programming. See, for example, [Object-Oriented Programming: Polymorphism in Python](https://renanmf.com/object-oriented-programming-polymorphism-in-python/).

```py
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

# This is an abstract class: method plot_data
# must be overriden in a subclass:
class data_reader(ABC):
     def __init__(self):
          self.load_data()
          self.common_method_1()
          self.common_method_2()

     def load_data(self):
          # Loads the data
          ...

     def common_method_1(self):
          # A method common for all data structures
          ...

     def common_method_2(self):
          # Another method common for all data structures
          ...

     # This method must be overridden in a subclass:
     @abstractmethod
     def plot_data(self):
          pass

class data_reader_1(data_reader):
     def plot_data(self):
          # Plotting function for data structure 1
          ...

class data_reader_2(data_reader):
     def plot_data(self):
          # Plotting function for data structure 2
          ...

class data_reader_3(data_reader):
     def plot_data(self):
          # Plotting function for data structure 3
          ...


if __name__ == "__main__":

     a = data_reader_1() # A specific subclass
     a.plot_data()
```

**If `load_data` must be specific for each subclass, then make it an abstract method (meaning it must be overridden in a subclass) in the base class and then define it for each subclass.**